# KDB select where x in other query result

Tags: kdb

I have a query

```
top:flip select [10] Name from `Val xdesc select sum Val by Name from table
```

and I want another query filtering based on that result

```
select from table where Name in top
```

however that gives me a type error. I also tried

```
select from table where {x in y}[Name; top]
```

but that yields an empty table. Any suggestions how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to `in` needs to be of list type, so you could do:

```
select from table where Name in exec Name from top
```

or:

```
select from table where Name in top[`Name]
```

You could also make `top` a list to begin with. Using the [take](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#take) operator to get the first 10 items in the sorted table:

```
top:10#(exec Name from `Val xdesc select sum Val by Name from table)
```

and then you would be able to do:

```
select from table where Name in top
```

Comment: Works perfect. would you mind explaining how that # works? cant find much documentation on this

Comment: Have edited with the link to the kx documentation. `#` is the "take" operator; in this example 10# takes the first 10 items from your sorted table